# return log function python returns typeerror: return arrays must be of arraytype

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, typeerror

I am writing a simple code. I have dataframe set up (logs)
the dataframe logs contain the column DT (float)

```
import numpy as np
dt_base=64.0
kp_dt=-0.0667

def delta_dt(dt_log,  db, kp):
  delta_dt = (np.log(kp*(dt_log-db),10))
  return delta_dt

logs['temp_x'] = delta_dt( logs['DT'],  dt_base, kp_dt)
```

This returns an error

> TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType

Any help? Thanks

Comment: What is the `10` in the `log` expression supposed to be doing?  Look at `np.log` documentation.  The 2nd argument, if given, is the `out` array.  It isn't a `base`.

Comment: When asking about an error like this, you should show the full traceback.  In this case it would show that the error occurs in the `np.log` line.

Comment: np.log(x,10) was the issue. I was using it like math.log format. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am sorry for not posting the entire script. This is my first post. I will be wise about that

Answer (score 0):

try doing `delta_dt = np.array(np.log(kp*(dt_log-db),10))`

Comment: unfortunately i can't test it properly cause i don't have the full script

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am sorry for not posting the entire script. This is my first post. I will be wise about that.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by changing the np.log() into np.log10. That seemed to be the issue.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve the issue. By the way, don't worry we've all been there lol. Good luck